# I can't run Maven war using "localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.jsp"

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss, maven-3, jboss7.x

I'm really hopeless, i spent to days searching on the net a solution for my pb but nothing helpful.. :/ could any one plz help me out

Im using eclipse,i have a simple maven war ( a hello world ,just for test) ,i deploy this war file in my Jboss 7.0.2 server and the file is deployed ..i even checked "Jboss Mangement ","Managemnt Deploy " section, and the war file is there.
every thing is fine until i want to run this maven war file,
localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.jsp but an error http404 takes place saying "the request resource (mywebapp/index.jsp") is not available.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can find a class file called `index_jsp.class` in the applications path `JBOSS/server/default/work/jboss.web/localhost/...`

If not then there is some problem with your war. Its always a good idea to check the startup logs for any errors.
Does your war include a WEB-INF/web.xml file? Check that file for some wrongly configured tag related to index.jsp

In your mywebapp war file, where is index.jsp placed - is it directly under `mywebapp` or inside `mywebapp/WEB-INF`. If it is the latter you cannot access it directly, you must have the required config in web.xml